# Showing secondary nav on one page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, navigation

I have this bit of code in my header:

```
        <?php if (has_nav_menu('sub-header-menu', 'responsive')) { ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                'container'       => '',
                'menu_class'      => 'sub-header-menu',
                'theme_location'  => 'sub-header-menu')
                ); 
            ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

And I need something that will make it only show on the blog page and the children for that page (i.e the categories).. I'm not great with PHP but I guess this would be something simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a page Id of your blog page in you condition.

```
$parentPageId = is_subpage();
if (has_nav_menu('sub-header-menu', 'responsive') &&
   (is_page( $blogPageId ) || $parentPageId == $blogPageId))
```

You can alos check your page using *slug*.

```
is_page( 'blog' )
```

Function to get Parent Page Id if exists.

```
function is_subpage() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
        return $post->post_parent;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've put that in but the menu seems to be showing on every page now

Comment: Can you post the value of `$blogPageId`, `$parentPageId` you getting in any other page than blog ?

Comment: @user1738017 - You should know your blog page id which you need to assign to  the variable `$blogPageId`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28799/discussion-between-rikesh-and-user1738017)

Answer (score 0):

Find out the ID of the blog page `$blogid = 123` (for example) and then check with `if ($page->ID == $blogid) { /*show menu*/ }`